# Assigning value from a string to an enum data member

Tags: c#

I have a class named MettingRoom.

Which has data members as follows:

```
Boolean hasProjector,
PropertyOptions property
```

PropertyOptions goes like this

```
public enum PropertyOptions
{        
    [EnumMember]
    Off = 0,        
    [EnumMember]
    Automatic = 1,        
    [EnumMember]
    On = 2,
}
```

Now I have a function to set values to these data members

```
MeetingRoom setOptions(string hasProjectorValue, string propertyValue)
{        
    return new MeetingRoom()
    {                    
        hasProjector = bool.Parse(hasProjectorValue),
        property = ???,        
    }
}
```

Property value would be either of On,Off,Automatic.
My question is how do I assign value to data member 'property'?

Comment: why is [EnumMember] you do not need to do that anyone that knows what an enum is can tell that Off, Automatic, and On, are members of that Enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `propertyValue` string into the `PropertyOptions` enum by parsing it:

```
property = (VotingValue)Enum.Parse(typeof(PropertyOptions), propertyValue);
```

However, the above will throw an exception if the parsing failed. You may want to use `Enum.TryParse` instead:

```
MeetingRoom setOptions(string hasProjectorValue, string propertyValue)
{
    PropertyOptions prop;

    Enum.TryParse(propertyValue, true, out prop)

    return new MeetingRoom()
    {                    
        hasProjector = bool.Parse(hasProjectorValue),
        property = prop
    }
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It gives an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to propertyOptions. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: @YuvrajSolanki, I revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case when `Enum.TryParse` isn't sufficient (e.g. you need to map obsolete value), it's quite a good idea to use some sort of mapping, i.e.

```
static class PropertyOptionsConvertor
{
    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyOptions>() Mapping = new Dictionary<string, PropertyOptions>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "on",    PropertyOptions.On },
        { "off",   PropertyOptions.Off },
        // other members...
    };

    public static bool GetOptions(string value, out PropertyOptions result)
    {
        if (Mapping.TryGetValue(value, out result))
        {
            return true;
        }

        result = default(PropertyOptions);
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can also make a generic version of this and have it map string to anything for the matter. The internal mapping would then be supplied through constructor.